# Unable to enable Windows subsystem for Linux in Windows 11

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Whenever I go to `Control Panel > Programs > Turn Windows features on and off`, select the "Windows subsystem for Linux" checkbox, press "ok" and restart my laptop, then the Windows subsystem for Linux remains unenabled; when I go back to `Control Panel > Programs > Turn Windows features on and off`, its checkbox is still unckecked. When I try to enable it through PowerShell with `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux` it shows no errors, but doesn't enable it either.

When I run `wsl --install` in PowerShell, I first get

```
Installing: Virtual Machine Platform 
Virtual Machine Platform has been installed
Installing: Windows Subsystem for Linux
Windows Subsystem for Linux has been installed.
The requested operation is successful. Changes will not be effective until the system is rebooted.
```

And after rebooting

```
No action was taken as a system reboot is required.
```

I also do  have Hardware Virtualization enabled.

Comment: Do you have Hardware Virtualization enabled?  What have when you run `wsl --install` you should [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment.  I also assume you have successfully ran and installed `Virtual Machine Platform ` by running `dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart`

Comment: I've seen this happen before -- *"it shows no errors"*.  Typically, the error will appear during the reboot, but we often look away or step away from our screens when rebooting, so we miss it.  Is there any chance that, during reboot, it says something about rolling back the changes?

Comment: @Ramhound I don't *think* that virtualization would come into play at this stage.  Keep in mind that the "Windows Subsystem for Linux" optional feature can be used to enable WSL1 without requiring any virtualization or the VMP.  Virtualization is only required *when* enabling the VMP (which, along with the kernel download, enables WSL2).  Maybe something changed recently, but the [doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-1---enable-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux) still says that "Step 1" can be performed without ever proceeding to the WSL2 portions.

Comment: Still would be interested in having that additional information

Comment: Getting the same error. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @live-love unfortunatley, no